# The view area of ckEditor sometimes shows empty at the start

Tags: ckeditor

I am using the following directive to create a ckEditor view. There are other lines to the directive to save the data but these are not included as saving always works for me.

```
app.directive('ckEditor', [function () {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function ($scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {
            var ck = ck = CKEDITOR.replace(elm[0]);

            ngModel.$render = function (value) {
            ck.setData(ngModel.$modelValue);
            setTimeout(function () {
                ck.setData(ngModel.$modelValue);
            }, 1000);
        };            }
    };
}])
```

The window appears but almost always the first time around it is empty. Then after clicking the [SOURCE] button to show the source and clicking it again the window is populated with data.

I'm very sure that the ck.setData works as I tried a ck.getData and then logged the output to the console. However it seems like ck.setData does not make the data visible at the start.

Is there some way to force the view window contents to appear?

Comment: how is the model changed?

Comment: I added the answer to the question.

Comment: how is `$scope.editRow` called? is it within an $apply loop

Comment: the render is called as part of watcher cycle

Comment: Arun I added some more information. My user clicks on an icon in a grid and this calls the editRow function passing the contents of that row.  That function then copies the row data to an object that is used for the modal fields.

Comment: this is why I use redactor as an editor. It does everything CK does but better and the directive is simple and works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a fairly simple answer to the question. I checked the DOM and found out the data was getting loaded in fact all of the time. However it was not displaying in the Chrome browser. So the problem is more of a display issue with ckEditor. Strange solution seems to be to do a resize of the ckEditor window which then makes the text visible.

Answer (score 1):

You can call render on the model at any time and it will simply do whatever you've told it to do.  In your case, calling `ngModel.$render()` will grab the `$modelValue` and pass it to `ck.setData()`.  Angular will automatically call `$render` whenever it needs to during its digest cycle (i.e. whenever it notices that the model has been updated).  However, I have noticed that there are times when Angular doesn't update properly, especially in instances where the `$modelValue` is set prior to the directive being compiled.

So, you can simply call `ngModel.$render()` when your modal object is set.  The only problem with that is you have to have access to the `ngModel` object to do that, which you don't have in your controller.  My suggestion would be to do the following:

In your controller:

```
$scope.editRow = function (row, entityType) {
   $scope.modal.data = row;
   $scope.modal.visible = true;
   ...
   ...
   // trigger event after $scope.modal is set
   $scope.$emit('modalObjectSet', $scope.modal);  //passing $scope.modal is optional
}
```

In your directive:

```
ngModel.$render = function (value) {
    ck.setData(ngModel.$modelValue);
};

scope.$on('modalObjectSet', function(e, modalData){
    // force a call to render
    ngModel.$render();
});
```

Its not a particularly clean solution, but it should allow you to call `$render` whenever you need to.  I hope that helps.

UPDATE: (after your update)

I wasn't aware that your controllers were nested.  This can get really icky in Angular, but I'll try to provide a few possible solutions (given that I'm not able to see all your code and project layout).  Scope events (as noted [here](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0rc1/docs/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope)) are specific to the nesting of the scope and only emit events to child scopes.  Because of that, I would suggest trying one of the three following solutions (listed in order of my personal preference):

1) Reorganize your code to have a cleaner layout (less nesting of controllers) so that your scopes are direct decendants (rather than sibling controllers).

2) I'm going to assume that `1)` wasn't possible.  Next I would try to use the `$scope.$broadcast()` function.  The specs for that are listed [here](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0rc1/docs/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope) as well.  The difference between `$emit` and `$broadcast` is that $emit only sends event to child $scopes, while $broadcast will send events to both parent **and** child scopes.

3) Forget using `$scope` events in angular and just use generic javascript events (using a framework such as `jQuery` or even just roll your own as in the example [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-custom-events/))

Comment: I am posting for Melina as she can't get access to her computer just now. The solution you provided looks good but we can't get the directive to receive the emitted message. I wonder is this because the HTML is handled in a different controller. Melina added some more lines to the question to describe this. Do you think it would work if we used broadcast or did the emit with rootscope? When we trace the code the emit gets called but when we set a breakpoint inside the $scope.$on('modalObjectSet' ...  it never reaches the breakpoint. Please let us know if you have some ideas. Thanks

Comment: I added more info to my response that explains my best attempts to fix the issue you've described above

Comment: I tried the changes mentioned but still no luck. I did find something that seems to fix the problem but the solution does not seem good. I will update the question with what I have found.

Answer (score 1):

This is a strange issue with ckeditor when your ckeditor is hidden by default. Trying to show the editor has a 30% chance of the editor being uneditable and the editor data is cleared. If you are trying to hide/show your editor, use a css trick like `position:absolute;left-9999px;` to hide the editor and just return it back by css. This way, the ckeditor is not being removed in the DOM but is just positioned elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Use this java script code that is very simple and effective.Note **editor1** is my textarea id

```
<script>
  $(function () {
    CKEDITOR.timestamp= new Date();
    CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
  });
</script>
```

**Second way** In controller ,when your query is fetch data from database then use th

---

is code after .success(function().

```
 $http.get(url).success(function(){
   CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know, that this thread is dead for a year, but I got the same problem and I found another (still ugly) solution to this problem:

```
instance.setData(html, function(){
  instance.setData(html);
});
```